# Time taken to import 100Gb of data from RDBMS to hadoop using Sqoop

Tags: hadoop, import, hive, sqoop

I was searching for a answer for this question , but didnt find any suitable answer yet.

I am talking about a small cluster 
Cluster Size -  18, 1 MN ,1SN,16 DN. 2 racks.Each size 1*2 TB. 16gb. 1G Rack Level switch, with 10G Uplink 24 port, Processing data size of 2-300 GBs per week. Replication factor 3.

For the above config , how much time it should take to import around 100GB of data. I know there will be many other factors to consider, but an average time will help me .

Comment: There is not way to estimate your very specific question without your environment to run the tests. This is not a valid question for this site.

Comment: I think it is a very valid question to have an idea, if it completes in seconds, minutes hrs or days

Comment: Please visit the tour http://stackoverflow.com/tour. Your question is a **primarly opinion-based** and it is not a good question in StackOverflow format.

Comment: I found the answer by doing it practically.

Now I am waiting for someone else to compare mine.

It takes about 2.2 hrs for 1oo gb in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider any tuning/optimizations before the test?

Comment: Yes, I have tried few tunings which is possible with above mentioned configuration .